# Error message "barrier-based sync failed".

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon Linux EC2 AMI, recently I'm getting this error "barrier-based sync failed" every 10 days.

Running Services

```
Apache
MySQL
Memcached Server
PHP
```

Comment: Do you get this message in syslog? Do you use Open Enterprise Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an error message.

It is an informative log message which indicate that the hardware (or the storage driver) does not support cache flush command. These messages occur normally.

To stop the log message from being logged, 
either remount the filesystem using the nobarrier option.

E.g. `mount -o remount,nobarrier /dev/path /path/tomountpoint` or pass the option `barrier=off` to the kernel on boot.

See [here](http://vnluck.com/2011/11/jbd-barrier-based-sync-failed-on-md0-8-%E2%80%93-disabling-barriers-error-and-solution/) and [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/11/8/493) for more information.